# Magento Enterprise constantly goes to installation, even though I set the DB from the dump

Tags: magento-enterprise, enterprise-1.14

I have a database dump from an old development machine for my Magento Enterprise (version 1.14.1.0), and I set the secure and unsecured URL correctly in the database so that it points to my files correctly.

I am constantly being redirected to the installation process.

How can I skip this and what is causing Magento to try to do the installation from the beginning?

I am a Magento Enterprise total noob though.

Comment: Did you checked local.xml file  ? it will be in app/etc/local.xml 
Check if file exist? if yes then kindly check permission for it.

Comment: Did I checked it for what?

Comment: i have updated my comment.

Comment: app/etc/local.xml has 777 permission

Comment: could you  please share your local.xml ?